# How to make documents, listitems, websites low ranked in the search result?

Tags: search, ranking

I would like to make all content from for example webapplicationX or siteCollectionX low ranked programmatically. So when the site collection owner clicks on the button "archive" I would like to loop into all content of this site collection (websites, documents, list items, everything) and make it low ranked.

If someone search on some keyword the results of this site collection will be somewhere on last pages.

Answer (score 5):

From the site your archiving via Site Settings go to Manage Query Rules (or from Search Service Application page i Central Admin go to Query Rules).

[image]

On the Manage Query Rules page, select Recently Changed items and push the button New Query Rule.

[image]

On the Add Query Rule page, enter a rule name, remove the default condition and follow the ling Change ranked results by changing the query.

[image]

On the Build Your Query page, select the Sorting tab. Select sort by Rank, and Change Ranking when: Url matches exactly. Paste your Site Collection URL and select Demote to bottom. Click OK, and save on the next screen.

[image]

Now you have demoted your archived site collection and all of its content to the bottom.

[image]